# How can I test local installation of an NPM package I've published?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-publish

I recently published a [package to NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hub-batch). The package works well on my own computer, where I wrote the code, but upon `npm install` on a coworkers machine, I start receiving errors.

What is the best way to go about installing and testing my package on my own computer? I could trace through the errors on my coworkers computer, but I assume there is a way I can do this on my own machine.

Comment: delete your node_modules folder and retry?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that. I'll give it a try.

Comment: You should really consider using Jasmine or Karma for Unit Testing and Protractor for E2E testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't have to install it on your own computer first if you want to test it, you could write unit tests instead, since you have to `require` the package if you do (just like an npm install).
2. Check the `package.json` to see if all needed modules are listed under `dependencies`. (Delete the node_modules folder, run `npm install` and see what errors are given)
3. If there is a file called `.npmrc`, check what files/folders it lists to make sure it's not excluding important files from NPM.
4. Make sure your module has a `module.exports` object, to be able to access the objects/functions

If this all didn't help, it might be a more specific problem and a GitHub link would help us more